# Unable to find element using xpath with Appium (robot framework)

Tags: android, xpath, robotframework, appium

I am unable to identify element using xpath. I tried different types of xpath but could not identify it.

I want to identify the element "Bills" shown in the below pic.
I don't have ID, so I am using xpath. I used below xpaths.

xpath=//android.app.ActionBar$Tab/TextView[@text='Bills'] and xpath=//android.app.ActionBar$Tab[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkrfZ.jpg)/TextView[@text='Bills']

Please help me. I am struck here.

[image]

Comment: After further exploration, I came to know this is happening because of $ (Special character) used for one of the nodes. 
Does someone have any idea how to deal with such cases.

Note: I have tried using giving back slash. But it did not work for me.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the chars with `\\` instead of a single backslash?

Comment: For the record I had "\\" but I didn't check.. To clarify: Have you tried escaping the chars with double backslash instead of a single?

Answer (score 2):

You should use "class" of each selector for your xpath:

```
xpath=//android.widget.TextView[@text='Bills']
```

and if this wouldn't work, it means that you should add some previous classes (in higher hierarchy) in front of this one for this xpath to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't seem to have any other element with the same properties, it might work if you remove the problematic part from the xpath and try with just:

```
xpath=//TextView[@text='Bills']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

xpath=(//android.widget.TextView[@text='Bills'])[1]

Its clear that there is index for this element from the UI Automator Viewer

Note:Group Index starts from 1.

Answer (score -1):

Some times above xpath won't work.. it could be start from their parent elements like below,for eg:

```
Xpath=//android.widget.linerlayout[1]/android.widget.linerlayout[1]/android.widget.TextView[@text='Bills']
```

Comment: This is terrible solution from best coding practices point of view. I would suggest such implementations only as a last resort solutions.